# UPS worldship "date" field is in an unusable format

Tags: ms-access

I export records from UPS Worldship to Access and the date field called "Collectiondate" is not in a standard date/time format.  Instead it outputs like "20110928" , but I want it to output like "9/28/11". please advise
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Starting with your string value, "20110928", you can transform it to a string which the CDate() function will recognize as a valid date ("2011-09-28").

```
Debug.Print Left("20110928", 4) & "-" & Mid("20110928", 5, 2) & "-" & _
    Right("20110928", 2)
```

You can then use CDate() to convert the string to a Date/Time value, and use Format() to convert that back to a string in your desired format.

```
Debug.Print Format(CDate(Left("20110928", 4) & "-" & Mid("20110928", 5, 2) & _
    "-" & Right("20110928", 2)), "m/d/yy")
```

Since the string is in a field, Collectiondate, you can do something similar with a SELECT query.

```
SELECT Format(CDate(Left(Collectiondate, 4) & "-" & Mid(Collectiondate, 5, 2) & 
        "-" & Right(Collectiondate, 2)), "m/d/yy") AS Formatted_Collectiondate
FROM UPS_CSV_EXPORT;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying to my question... I accidentally forgot to provide you with the table name.  please apply my table name "UPS_CSV_EXPORT" to your select query, so I can copy and paste, as I dont know SQL.

Comment: the output is in "text" format, but I need it in "date" format, so that I can run additional queiries based on the date value.  Pplease provide me with the proper SQL to copy and paste. Thank you very much in advance